# Why is not my stored procedure executing CLR method with some id's?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, .net-assembly, sqlclr

In short, I have a CLR method for send emails to users from SQL Server. I have all my data information about body, attachments, subject, emails, etc in my SQL Server tables. Well, I'm doing an app in C# to do this, I haven't get troubles for save information with stored procedures in tables but when I want to execute my SP sending id(mail). This says 'Command completed successfully' but mail don't send. Then I test executing my SP from SQL Server manually and send correctly some id's and some don't 'watch' my method for send, because this execute commands correctly but do anything. Why is happening this? Someone has have this issue before??

This is my CLR Method

```
[SqlProcedure]
    public static int CustomMethod(int id_email, out string sError)
    {
        int mReturn = 0;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sError = string.Empty;
        Dictionary<int, string> ListFile = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        try
        {                
            ds = retornarQuery(strQuery: "ZeusFW_Email_List " + id_email);
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i];
                    string ds_to_name = (string)row["ds_to_name"];
                    string ds_to_email = (string)row["ds_to_email"];
                    string ds_cc_email = (string)row["ds_cc_email"];
                    string ds_bcc_email = (string)row["ds_bcc_email"];
                    string ds_idiom = (string)row["ds_idiom"];
                    string ds_subject = (string)row["ds_subject"];
                    string ds_body = (string)row["ds_body"];
                    int am_sent_times = (int)row["am_sent_times"];
                    int in_process = (int)row["in_process"];
                    int am_email_port = (int)row["am_email_port"];
                    string ds_email_host = (string)row["ds_email_host"];
                    string ds_email_user = (string)row["ds_email_user"];
                    string ds_email_password = (string)row["ds_email_password"];
                    int am_email_html = (int)row["am_email_html"];
                    int am_email_ssl = (int)row["am_email_ssl"];
                    string ds_email_name = (string)row["ds_email_name"];
                    string ds_email_xsl = (string)row["ds_email_xsl"];
                    int in_email_log = (int)row["in_email_log"];
                    DeliveryNotificationOptions am_notificationoptions = NotificationOptions((int)row["am_notificationoptions"]);
                    MailPriority am_priority = Priority((int)row["am_priority"]);
                    if (in_process == 0 && am_email_html == 1)
                    {
                        ds_body = DoXSLT(ds_body, ds_email_xsl);
                    }
                    ZeusFrameworkSmtp.ZeusFrameworkSmtp email = new ZeusFrameworkSmtp.ZeusFrameworkSmtp();
                    email.AddFrom = ds_email_user;
                    email.AddName = ds_email_name;
                    email.AddTo.Add(ds_to_email);
                    if (ds_cc_email != null || !ds_cc_email.Equals("")) email.AddCC = ds_cc_email;
                    if (ds_bcc_email != null || !ds_bcc_email.Equals("")) email.AddBcc = ds_bcc_email;
                    if (am_sent_times > 0) { ds_subject = "Re#" + am_sent_times + " " + ds_subject; }
                    email.Subject = ds_subject;
                    email.Body = ds_body;
                    email.BodyHtml = (am_email_html == 0 ? false : true);
                    email.Server = ds_email_host;
                    email.Port = am_email_port;
                    email.User = ds_email_user;
                    email.Password = ds_email_password;
                    email.EnableSsl = (am_email_ssl == 0 ? false : true); ;
                    email.NotificationOptions = am_notificationoptions;
                    email.Priority = am_priority;
                    am_sent_times = am_sent_times + 1;
                    if (ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count - 1; j++)
                        {
                            DataRow rowAttachments = ds.Tables[1].Rows[j];
                            if (id_email == (int)rowAttachments["id_email"])
                            {
                                if ((int)rowAttachments["in_delete_file"] == 1) ListFile.Add(j, (string)rowAttachments["ds_full_path"]);
                                email.AddAttachments.Add((string)rowAttachments["ds_full_path"]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    bool bresult = email.Send(out sError);
                    //if (bresult) { mReturn = 1; Database.ZeusFW_Email_Update(id_email, am_sent_times, sError, in_email_log).Run(); }
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sError) || sError.Equals("ESTOY EJECUTANDO EL METODO")) sError = "Operación completada con éxito.";
                    if (ListFile.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> item in ListFile)
                        {
                            if (item.Key == 1) File.Delete(item.Value.ToString());
                        }
                        ListFile.Clear();
                    }
                }
            }
            else sError = "No se encontró el ID";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            //sError = sError + "-" + "Error executing SQL statement information: " + ex.Message + "id_email : " + id_email.ToString() + "Conn : " + Database.ConnectionString + ex.StackTrace.ToString();

            LogWindows _LogWindows = new LogWindows();
            _LogWindows.Save("Zeus", sError, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
            //SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Error executing SQL statement information: " + ex.Message + "id_email> " + id_email_aux.ToString() + "Conn>" + Database.ConnectionString);
        }
        return mReturn;
    }
```

This my Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CustomMethod]
@id_email int
,@sError nvarchar(2000)=NULL OUTPUT
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
EXTERNAL NAME [AssemblyNamespace].[AssemblyNamespace.AssemblyNamespace1].[CustomMethod]
GO
```

[image: Don't Work]
[image: Work perfect]

Both ID's exist in my sql table like valid mails. Ignore names of SP is for privacity they have same name in CLR method and Stored Procedure

I've got this Exception in SQL Server.

> Mens 6522, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Procedimiento ZeusFW_EmailqueueUnit_SendOutError, Línea 2
>   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "ZeusFW_EmailqueueUnit_SendOutError":
>
> System.IO.IOException: El sistema no puede ponerse en contacto con un controlador de dominio para que atienda la solicitud de autenticación. Inténtelo de nuevo más tarde.
>
> System.IO.IOException:
>     en System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>     en System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
>     en System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
>     en System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
>     en System.Net.Mail.AttachmentBase.SetContentFromFile(String fileName, String mediaType)
>     en System.Net.Mail.Attachment..ctor(String fileName)
>     en ZeusFrameworkSmtp.ZeusFrameworkSmtp.Send(String& error)
>     en AssemblyZeusSMTP.AssemblyZeusSMTP.ZeusFW_EmailqueueUnit_SendOutError(SqlInt32 id_email, SqlString& sError)

Comment: We can take a look at your code if you post it.

Comment: I've got the error. When I uso my CLR from my app this throw an exception System.IO.Exception: System cannot contact a domain controller to service the authentication request. Try later Somones knows why is happening? When I insert a row manually from sql server and execute my sp this send correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some things to look at:

1. Please use the `Sql*` types instead of the native .NET types for input and output parameters for the SQLCLR public methods. So the signature should be:

   ```cs
   public static SqlInt32 CustomMethod(SqlInt32 id_email, out SqlString sError)
   ```

   You can get the native values out of any of those types via the `.Value` property that they all have (e.g. `id_email.Value`).
2. You went through the trouble of passing back the status code, so capture it so you can see more of what is going on. In the C# code, assign a non-zero value to `mReturn` based on `bresult`:

   ```cs
   if (bresult)
   {
     mReturn = 1;
   }
   else
   {
     mReturn = 2;
   }
   ```

   And then change your T-SQL to be:

   ```sql
   DECLARE @id_email INT,
           @sError NVARCHAR(4000),
           @return_code INT;

   SET @id_email = 37;

   EXEC @return_code = dbo.ZeusFW_EmailQueueUnit_SendOutError
           @id_email,
           @sError OUTPUT;

   SELECT @return_code AS [ReturnCode],
          N'~' + @sError + N'~' AS [ErrorMessage],
          DATALENGTH(@sError) AS [ErrorMessageBytes];
   ```
3. Looking at the posted code, it seems like the only ways to get an empty string for `@sError` (is it really empty?) are:

   1. `email.Send()` is actually passing back a non-empty string of white-space and/or other non-printable characters. The T-SQL shown above has been adjusted to check for this.
   2. the code is getting an exception, in which case you should see something in the Windows Event Log (since you are saving an entry there). Have you checked the Windows Event Log?
4. Is there any logging in the Zeus framework that you can check?
5. **Most importantly:** why are you sending emails from SQLCLR when SQL Server has a built-in function for this, one that is asynchronous? It can handle file attachments, HTML email bodies, etc. Please look into swapping out this SQLCLR Stored Procedure for a T-SQL Stored Procedure that calls [sp_send_dbmail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) (introduced in SQL Server 2008, or possibly even 2005).

Other notes:

- Life will be easier, and your code more readable, if you stop prefixing variables with the datatype. So use `Result` instead of `mReturn`, `Result` instead of `bResult`, and `ErrorMessage` instead of `sError`. This goes for working in both C# and T-SQL.
- There is no need to subtract `1` from a `Count` in a loop as that forces you to use `<=` instead of just `<`. Using `j < ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count` is logically the same, one less (unnecessary) operation, and more readable :-).

Comment: Thank you @srutzky

Comment: I've got the error. When I uso my CLR from my app this throw an exception `System.IO.Exception: System cannot contact a domain controller to service the authentication request. Try later` Somones knows why is happening? When I insert a row manually from sql server and execute my sp this send correctly. @srutzky

Comment: @ChristianTorresM You would need to post the entire stack trace for that error message (the IO exception). It is possible it is coming from the Zeus framework. Also, what does "inserting a row manually" have to do with this? The code that you posted doesn't show any INSERT commands.

Comment: I don't show but my system save in a table the mail that you want to send and another table save attachment with id-mail. Well I do this manually and my sp works fine. But when I do from my app crash with that exception.

Comment: @ChristianTorresM If you are running this from app code, why are you creating a SQLCLR stored procedure? why not just call Zeus from the app code where you already are? This seems very odd.  Can the app at least insert the rows? Is there error coming from the insert or the call to the SQLCLR stored procedure? What is the rest of the exception message (i.e. the stack trace)?

Comment: @ChristianTorresM That is all text. Please update the question and place that text (not the image) at the end of the question. Thanks. But yes, the issue is within Zeus. Is your app code connection with a SQL Server login or a trusted connection / integrated security?

Comment: I had standard connection but I tried with `SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"context connection=true");` and keep same issue :(

Comment: @ChristianTorresM I just saw that this was accepted (thanks). What was the specific issue or change that you made? The info you provided above about using `Context Connection` didn't make sense. And I was going to say that the issue sounds like an Impersonation/Delegation issue that might be related to the service account for the MSSQLSERVER process.

Comment: Hi @srutzky. Well In my app I'm using a standard connection with SqlConnection and ConnectionString. I think that my issue trigger when I try attach files, I'm not sure but I have a sme method without attachments and works always.

Comment: @ChristianTorresM Yes, the issue is specifically permissions when accessing the file system for the attachments. You can see that the error path (in the stack trace) shows `System.Net.Mail.Attachment` and then `System.IO.FileStream.Init` right before the error. This is why I asked if you were using a SQL Server login or a trusted connection. But now that I look again, it is most likely due to the service account for the MSSQLSERVER process (assuming a default instance). That account needs access to where the files are.

Comment: Oh @srutzky I understand. How can I grant the access? I've never done this.

Comment: @ChristianTorresM You first need to find the service account for the MSSQLSERVER service.  You can find that in the Services area in Control Panel. Then, add that account to the NTFS permissions of whatever folder the attachments are in.